# Como criar e conectar usuários em novas rooms com soket.io

Tags: php, jquery, node.js, socket.io

estou utilizando `socket.io 1.3.5` e `express 4.12.3` para criar aplicação de chat em meu `script php`, porém não sei a lógica de criar nova room quando um usuário chama outro.
Em miúdos: sei criar uma room para cada usuário e `linkar` este pedido em um evento e para dois usuários funciona de boa porém quando outro usuário chama ai mistura tudo...

Como fazer para criar uma room para cada nova chamada?